# DB role in a WSO2 Identity Server Clustered Deployment

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to set up a cluster of WSO2 Identity Servers for HA.  From the documentation I understand that there can be two IS nodes which are load-balanced either through ELB or Apache.

In my case the user-store will be an Active Directory server.

My question is around the database requirements for the cluster.  Given that the user store is AD, what kind of a database setup do I need?  Do I need a database cluster such as MySQL (which makes sense for HA), and what would it be used for?

Comment: You no need of separate database cluster. You can share the databases across the IS clustered instances.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+Identity+Server
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Setting+up+the+Database

Comment: You can share a single database server among instances but a cluster is good for HA.  Moreover my question was more around what is the database used for if the user store is external AD.

Comment: You mean what type of database server need to use if user store is external AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user store is AD and database can be anything.  There is no any special recommendation for databases. You can use any SQL database but WSO2IS has been only tested with following database types.`H2, DB2, MsSQL, MySQL, MySQL Cluster, Oracle, Oracle RAC,PostgreSQL, Informix.sql`   You can use any of these. But embedded H2 is not production recommended. Also database does not depend on the user store that you are using. You can use any type of user store (JDBC,AD,LDAP) and any type of database independently.  As you have mentioned,  it would be better, if you can have database level clustering to achieve the HA. If you are using MySQL,  you can probably use the MySQL cluster,  more detail would be available in the WSO2 [article](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/04/deploying-wso2-platform-mysql-cluster/) as well

Comment: Apart from the registry is anything else expected to be stored in the database?  I am trying to get a feel of how big/small the DB will be.

Comment: above article is little bit old..  with IS 5.0.0,  you have registry /  user-mgt/ identity  DB...  you can keep all data in one DB...  but it is better to connect registry DB in to one database and  Identity/user-mgt  in to another database..  Usually,   "Identity/user-mgt "  data would be high..  because all end user data would be stored there..  SSO sessions/access tokens/permission  and more....  therefore it would grow fast..   Registry would have few data such as policies... it is not growing

Comment: what type of cluster Mysql is supported by ISKM? checking the new version of ISKM (version 7.0) revealed that its dbscript (mysql_cluster.sql) is still using NDB Cluster... how to use  InnoDB Cluster ?